# R Shiny sliderInput with NO labeling?

Tags: r, slider, shiny

Is it possible to NOT have the `min`, `max`, or current value show on a shiny slider?  I want to use a slider as an increase or decrease mechanism, but I don't really want to show the values below of: 2, 30, or 5.

```
sliderInput("colornum","Change Bin Amount:",2, 30, 5, ticks = FALSE )
```

Answer (score 3):

You need some JavaScript for this. In the code below, I added a JavaScript function that is executed shortly after the slider initializes. This script selects the elements that are made for showing the current values and min/max value. We can just delete those elements. There will be no problem for Shiny, since those elements are only for display.

For any other sliderInput, copy the exact script and add the corresponding slider id, where it now reads `colornum`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      sliderInput("colornum","Change Bin Amount:",2, 30, 5, ticks = FALSE),
      tags$script(HTML("
        $(document).ready(function() {setTimeout(function() {
          supElement = document.getElementById('colornum').parentElement;
          $(supElement).find('span.irs-max, span.irs-min, span.irs-single, span.irs-from, span.irs-to').remove();
        }, 50);})
      "))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output){}
)
```